# How can i fix this issue in making a scroll view programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, scrollview

**FastNavigator**
How can i fix this issue in making a scroll view programatically?

```
class FastNavigator: UIView {

    var scrollView : UIScrollView!
    var scrollSubviews : [UIView]!
    var size :CGFloat = 0

    func configure(subviews:[UIView]){
        scrollSubviews = subviews

        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: self.frame)
        self.addSubview(scrollView)

        for view in scrollSubviews {

            scrollView.addSubview(view)
            view.frame = CGRect(x: 0 + size  , y: 0, width: scrollView.frame.width, height: scrollView.frame.height)
            size += view.frame.size.width
            print(size)
        }
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: size, height: scrollView.frame.height)
    }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let fast = FastNavigator()
    let myImages = ["mahmoud.jpg","ziad.jpg","farah.jpg","zinji.jpg"]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var subViews : [UIImageView] = []
        for imageName in myImages {

            let myUIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: Bundle.main.path(forResource: imageName, ofType: "")!)
            let imageView = UIImageView(image: myUIImage)
            subViews.append(imageView)
        }
        fast.frame = self.view.frame
        fast.configure(subviews: subViews)
        self.view.addSubview(fast)
    }
}
```

And am always getting this

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Check this may be helpfull for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442414/libcabi-dylib-terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-lldb

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814576/terminating-with-uncaught-exception-of-type-nsexception-in-swift

Comment: Thank you solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Go to Breakpoint Navigator, click add ("+" button), "Exception Breakpoint", RMB, "Edit breakpoint", add action with "po $arg1". Now you got printed error of NSException. Please post your error here.

Comment: oups i already fixed this . it was because i added a scrollview in storyBoard and forgot to delete it .